# How to read the line that contains a string then extract this line without this string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file .txt that contains a specific line, like this

file.txt

```
.
.
T - Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers
.
A - Wood, M.A.
.
.
.
```

I would like to extract lines that contain a string, I tried with a simple script:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "T - " in line:
            o_t = line.rstrip('\n')
        elif "A - " in line:
            o_a = line.rstrip('\n')


o_T = o_t.split('T - ')
print (o_T)

o_A = o_a.split('A - ')
#o_Fname =
#o_Lname =
print (o_A)
```

my output:

```
['', 'Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers']
['', 'Wood, M.A.']
```

and my desired output:

```
Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers
Wood, M.A.
```

moreover, for the second ("Wood, M.A.") can I also extract the last name and first name.
So the final results will be:

```
 Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers
 Wood
 M.A.
```

Comment: So you're asking how to remove the first 4 characters of a string? And how to split a string on comma?

Comment: In split section You need to print o_T not o_t.

Comment: I am trying to eliminate the first two.

Comment: Yes you were right, I will correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `filter` to remove all empty elements from list.

**Ex:**

```
o_T = filter(None, o_t.split('T - '))
print (o_T)
o_A = filter(None, o_a.split('A - '))
print (o_A)
```

**Output:**

```
['Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers']
['Wood, M.A.']
```

Comment: Is there a way to dissociate the "o_A" in two
o_Fname = **M.A.** 
o_Ltname = **Wood**

Answer (score 1):

The fault in your case is that you print o_t instead of o_T (which is the result of the split operation).

However as others pointed out you could also approach this by removing the first 4 characters, by using regex `\w - (.+)`, then you could get all values. If you also need the first character, you could use `(\w) - (.+)`.

In addition to that, if you'd give your variables better names, you'd have a better life :)