# Extract each element of each list after the reading a file, Using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I think the other time I asked my question incorrectly [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50540460/how-to-read-the-line-that-contains-a-string-then-extract-this-line-without-this)

I have a file .txt, like this:

```
.
.
T - Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers
.
A - Wood, M.A.
.
.
.
```

I would like to extract a part in the lines and extract each element of each list, here is my script:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if "T - " in line:
            o_t = line.rstrip('\n')
        elif "A - " in line:
            o_a = line.rstrip('\n')

o_T = filter(None, o_t.split('T - '))
list_o_T = [o_T]
o_Title = list_o_T[0]
print (o_Title)

o_A = filter(None, o_a.split('A - '))
list_o_A = [o_A]
o_Lname = list_o_A[0]
o_Fname = list_o_A[1]
print (o_Lname)
print (o_Fname)
```

and my desired output:

```
Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers
Wood 
M.A.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I type a script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
from pathlib import Path

def main():
    for line in Path('file.txt').read_text().split('\n'):
        if 'T - ' in line:
            o_t = line.replace('T - ', '')
        elif 'A - ' in line:
            o_Lname, o_Fname = line.replace('A - ', '').split(', ')

    print(o_t)
    print(o_Lname)
    print(o_Fname)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output:

```
Python and Matplotlib Essentials for Scientists and Engineers
Wood
M.A.
```